# node-qunit doesn't include my source files in scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, qunit

I've installed node-qunit (stable) from npm, but can't seem to get any tests working. My source files don't seem to be included in scope.

./source/myscript.js:

```
var myObj = {
    a : true
}
```

./test/tests.js:

```
test("that a is true", function () {
     ok(myObj.a);
});
```

./test/runner.js:

```
var runner = require('qunit');
runner.run({
    code : './source/myscript.js',
    tests : './test/tests.js'
});
```

./Makefile:

```
test :
<tab>node ./test/testrunner.js

.PHONY: install test
```

If I run `make test`, I get a `'ReferenceError: myObj is not defined'` error. The source file does run, because it can throw errors. It just doesn't seem to be included in the global scope as it should. It doesn't work if I do it from the command line, as per the instructions in the [node-qunit readme](https://github.com/kof/node-qunit/blob/master/readme.md). Anyone have any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not exporting anything. Behind the scenes, node-qunit is using [`require`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#module.require) to load the specified modules. To expose variables when a module is `require`d, you have to add them to the [`exports`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#module.exports) object (or assign your own object to the `exports` variable)

(There's also a syntax error - `;` in the object literal)

This works for me:

./source/myscript.js:

```
exports.myObj = {
  a: true
}
```

./test/tests.js:

```
QUnit.module('tests')

test("that a is true", function () {
  ok(myObj.a)
})
```

./test/runner.js:

```
var runner = require('qunit')

runner.run({
  code : './source/myscript.js'
, tests : './test/tests.js'
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise you had to export stuff. And the `;` was just a typo in the question... I've taken it out.

Comment: Good edit too... makes it even more detailed for others who might find this question.

Comment: How would you go about exporting the object without modifying the original source file?